# ExecutorCompletionService runs only in a single thread, but ExecutorService uses all CPUs

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

I have a bunch of `Callable`s that I want to run in parallel and get the results for. I have 12 cores on my machine; the following code works as expected with 100% CPU usage:

```
exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreads);
for(Callable<T> job : jobs) exec.submit(job);
// System runs at 100% CPU.
```

However, this situation is not ideal because I want to process the results of the tasks as they return. Hence, I wrap the `ExecutorService` in a `CompletionService` which queues up the `Future`s as they are done:

```
exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreads);
ecs = new ExecutorCompletionService<T>(exec);
for(Callable<T> job : jobs) ecs.submit(job);
// System runs threads one at a time.
```

Now my code runs 12 times slower. After checking the underlying code I see that `ExecutorCompletionService` calls `execute()` on the `ExecutorService` rather than `submit()`, but I don't see how this would cause it to exhibit the weird behavior.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

**EDIT: There is no difference here. The slowdown was caused by a change to a different part of the code at the same time this change was made, and there was confusion between the two.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execute(...)` should perform the same as `submit(...)`.  The only difference is that `submit(...)` returns a `Future`.  The `ExecutorCompletionService` does not need the future since it is wrapping the submitted task in its own internal `Runnable`.

The performance change must be do to some other change.  I know you show us the ECS constructor but just to make sure, you are not passing in a bounded `BlockingQueue` to the `ExecutorCompletionService` right?  Using a bounded queue would stop the threads from completing and moving to the next job until the jobs were dequeued.

Can we see more of the code?

Comment: You are right, it is not being caused by this change, the slowdown comes afterward. I mistook the ostensible `ExecutorCompletionService` part for something else. We should delete the question?

Comment: No necessarily.  It might be useful for others.  Your choice.

Comment: I suppose it will be useful for others; the two should be the same. I'll leave it up for now.

Answer (score 0):

using the ExecutorService, can you collect the Futures returned by submit and get() their results?